# Unable to create session connecting to Cassandra

Tags: windows, go, cassandra, gocql

I am using this [gocql](https://github.com/gocql/gocql) package.

I am trying to get this example working.

```
func main() {
    // connect to the cluster
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3")
    cluster.ProtoVersion = 3
    cluster.Keyspace = "example"
    cluster.Consistency = gocql.Quorum
    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
       return
    }

    uuid := gocql.TimeUUID()
    fmt.Printf("UUID : %v", uuid)

    query := session.Query(`INSERT INTO tweet (timeline, id, text) VALUES         
    (?, ?, ?)`, "me", uuid, "hello world")

    fmt.Println("About to exec")
    err = query.Exec()

    // insert a tweet
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var id gocql.UUID
    var text string

    /* Search for a specific set of records whose 'timeline' column matches
     * the value 'me'. The secondary index that we created earlier will be
     * used for optimizing the search */
    if err := session.Query(`SELECT id, text FROM tweet WHERE timeline = ?     
    LIMIT 1`,"me").Consistency(gocql.One).Scan(&id, &text); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Tweet:", id, text)

    // list all tweets
    iter := session.Query(`SELECT id, text FROM tweet WHERE timeline = ?`, 
    "me").Iter()
    for iter.Scan(&id, &text) {
        fmt.Println("Tweet:", id, text)
    }
    if err := iter.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Using the Cassandra shell I have created the keyspace "example" and the table "tweet" and they all work fine.

However, when I run the program, it gives me this error:

```
2017/04/14 20:52:55 gocql: unable to dial control conn 192.168.1.3: dial tcp     
192.168.1.3:9042: i/o timeout
gocql: unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial 
hosts: dial tcp 192.168.1.3:9042: i/o timeoutpanic: runtime error: invalid 
memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x60236d]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/gocql/gocql.(*Session).Close(0x0)
    /home/mda/.local/go/src/github.com/gocql/gocql/session.go:344 +0x2d
```

For some reason, gocql is unable to dial the localhost connection, and it times out. I am not sure how to fix this and a stackoverflow and google search hasn't helped so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide notedool status and cassandra.yaml file from one of the nodes? I wouldn't really change the protocol version at all.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what to look for. But when i type "nodetool status" on the command promt, this is what i get.    **Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  182.43 KB  256          100.0%            ###some host ID  rack1**

Comment: the cassandra.yaml file is large. Is there any information in particular that you want from the cassandra.yaml file?  If it helps, i haven't changed anything in it. It is just as it was when i downloaded cassandra

Comment: Any luck with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yeah.... 127.0.0.1 works. Thanks!   Sorry for the late reply

Comment: No problem man :) always glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the ip addresses are not according to the cluster situation on your computer. After giving me the nodetool status I think you should update the `cluster := gocql.NewCluster` to have just the `127.0.0.1` address and not the addresses from example.

I think in reality you are just running single node cassandra local instance. Which is fine for development.

Basically:

```
cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
```

and just drop this line all together

```
cluster.ProtoVersion = 3
```

Comment: I initially set the protocol to 4. And it still produced the same error message.